# Notepad++ and Lisp: Is it possible to use Notepad++ for SBCL Lisp development?

Tags: user-interface, editor, lisp

Is it possible to use Notepad++ for SBCL Lisp development?
I have no intention in using Emacs and alike whatsoever. I would like to experiment with the language.

Edit: is it possible to run Lisp code in integrated mode? Think of IDE mode.

Comment: I nchecked the question but the info there is outdayed. We are now 2015.

Comment: Of course it's possible, you can use any text editor you want.

Comment: When a question was posed does not qualify to make a duplicate. In 2008 you could do it. Usually features are not removed from a text editor. The most important feature of editing is bracket matching, then identation (which won't be perfect unless the highlighter can see the prototypes of macros). Syntax highlighting isn't very useful, but [context coloring](https://youtu.be/b0EF0VTs9Dc?t=14m58s) would be awesome in any editor.

Comment: If you have no intention to use emacs, you have to become a person who has an intention to use emacs. You won't look back to notepad++ once you learn it, I guarantee that.